# Failed resolution of: Lcom/dropbox/chooser/android/R$layout;

Tags: dropbox, cordova-plugins

I got a problem when I want to **build jar file dropbox**. It's alway show the error
" E/AndroidRuntime(24171): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/dropbox/chooser/android/R$layout;" when I import dropboxchoosersdk.jar instead of all lib DropboxChooserSDK

[image]

It's run well when I reference all lib DropboxChooserSDK.

[image]

So I would like to build jar file Dropbox to setup auto build with gradle. Anyone got the same problem, please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that we need follow some steps :
- Try to clean gradle build "gradle clean build" in terminal.
- Then we config the gradle setting file missing.
    lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }

Here is my gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```